# How to find the server processing time by IIS logs?

Tags: performance, iis, logging, iis-7, iis-7.5

From IIS logs, I observed that it makes the entry in the logs once it gets acknowledgement from the client machine that requests are properly served. Hence, from the time taken the attribute of IIS logs we can say  that it has the client waiting time as well.

```
Time Taken In IIS Logs = Server Processing Time + Client Wait Time to download the response
```

These are the values that we get in IIS logs:

- Date (date)
- Time (time)
- Client IP Address (c-ip)
- User Name (cs-username)
- Method (cs-method)
- URI Stem (cs-uri-stem)
- URI Query (cs-uri-query)
- Protocol Status (sc-status)
- Win32 Status (sc-win32-status)
- Bytes Sent (sc-bytes)
- Time Taken (time-taken)
- Host (cs-host)
- User Agent (cs(User-Agent))
- Referer (cs(Referer))

**My question is that - Is there a way to find out only server processing time for each web request which serves by IIS?**

Comment: This question also confirms that client waiting time is also a part of time taken. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091878/difference-in-time-taken-in-iis-and-asp-net?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

**Is there a way to find out only server processing time for each web
 request which serves by IIS?**

Probably not with regular IIS logs, but try "Advanced Logging"
See
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging#custom

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Link you shared  helped but I am aware of performance counter logs which can give us mode detailed information and it is a separate thing. There are more ways to achieve it by instrumentation as well.

What I want here is that IIS knows when it gets a response from backend and waits for the client to download the response; so is there a way to find backend processing time simply by looking at IIS logs or we can set something in IIS to enable this counter?

Comment: @jitendrasingh I searched for IIS registry hacks that may disable the network time from time-taken without luck.

Comment: How about advanced IIS logging?